# AddOrUpdate not updating

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have a concurrent dictionary `_dict` of type `<byte[], int>`

I loop through the items of another list of strings (`list1`), and if the item exists as a key in `_dict`, I increment its value; if it doesn't, I add it to `_dict` and set its value to 1

```
foreach(byte[] item in list1)
{
  _dict.AddOrUpdate(item, 1, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
}
```

The problem is, even if the item already exists in `_dict`, it adds it again to `_dict` instead of updating it.

What's wrong with my code?

**Updated code block**

```
    internal class someClass
{
    public List<byte[]> list1 { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int> dict1 { get; set; } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        someClass obj = new someClass();

        if (obj.list1 != null && obj.list1.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (byte[] item in obj.list1)
            {
                // upsert operation (add if string not in dictionary; update by incrementing count if it does exist)
                obj.dict1.AddOrUpdate(item, 1, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"it adds it again to `_dict`"_ - that's not how dictionaries work: one key can be present only once. Please create a [mcve] and show how you determine the claimed behavior.

Comment: Instead of describing the code in English, consider pasting that code in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong from just those 3 lines of code, but if you posted the rest of the code with it, you'd probably get better feedback.

Comment: just posted more code

Comment: Isn't dict1 null? I don't see you creating an instance for that reference.

Comment: You are just making this up, aren't you? Now it's string... now it's byte[]...

Comment: I was trying to simplify it as much as possible at first, but now I am painting a more accurate picture

Comment: Are you expecting two different `byte[]` instances to compare equal? If so, this has nothing at all to do with `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: See my answer's edit containing a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've changed the key type from `string` to `byte[]`, now the behavior you are seeing is the correct one (initialy, the question contained `string` keys).

Because:

The dictionary compares the keys by using the default `IEqualityComparer`, which in the case of `byte[]` is simply comparing the reference.

Since two `byte[]` arrays are two different objects even if they contain the same elements, they will be treated as different keys.

Consider creating an `IEqualityComparer` implementation yourself and use it in this constructor:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary(
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

EDIT:
Here's a working example:

```
public class ByteArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{
    public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)     
            return false;       

        if(x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(byte[] array)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return array.Aggregate(17, (v, b) => v * 23 + b.GetHashCode(), v => v);
        }
    }
}

internal class someClass
{
    public List<byte[]> list1 = new List<byte[]>();
    public ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int> dict1  = new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int>(new ByteArrayComparer());
}

void Main()
{
    someClass obj = new someClass();

    obj.list1.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2 });
    obj.list1.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2 });
    obj.list1.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2 });
    obj.list1.Add(new byte[] { 2, 3 });
    obj.list1.Add(new byte[] { 2, 3 });
    obj.list1.Add(new byte[] { 3, 4 });

    if (obj.list1 != null && obj.list1.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (byte[] item in obj.list1)
        {
            // upsert operation (add if string not in dictionary; update by incrementing count if it does exist)
            obj.dict1.AddOrUpdate(item, 1, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The final content of obj.dict1 will be:

```
Key 01 02 
Value 3 

Key 02 03 
Value 2 

Key 03 04 
Value 1
```

Comment: did you use your IEqualityComparer  in your working example?

Comment: @IsaacBok Yes, I have.

Comment: does it know to use the IEqualityComparer you created based on the constructor ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @IsaacBok Check the constructor I've used for the dictionary. That's how I tell it which comparer to use, which in turn tells it how to compare byte arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to use byte[] as a dictionary key, because two different byte arrays will be compared by reference not the data inside. So, if you strongly need in byte[] as a dictionary key, you should write your own class for IEqualityComparer interface. For example:

```
public class ByteArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]> {
  public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y) {
    if ( x == null || x == null ) {
      return x.length == y.length;
    }
    return x.SequenceEqual(y);
  }
  public int GetHashCode(byte[] key) {
    return key.Sum(b => b);
  }
}
```